# What's best practice for creating Decorator-Mixins?

Tags: qooxdoo

I experimented with themes and decorators again and tried to implement a better Decorator-Mixin for qx.ui.decoration.MLinearBackgroundGradient which not only has a start and end color and position but can get an array of colors to style a label like this: [image]

In my testapplication this works really good but I don't think that it is an elegant way because of the regex'ing inside of the value of styles["background-image"].
But because this is a Mixin, I can't inherit from MLinearBackgroundGradient.

Should I copy the code from MLinearBackgroundGradient to my custom mixin and enhance the code and properties I need? That would be some kind of code duplication.

You can find my work-in-progress-class on the Qooxdoo playground: [Playground example of the mixin under construction](http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22qx.Mixin.define(%2522MExtendedLinearBackgroundGradient%2522%252C%2520%257B%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520properties%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520textFillColor%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520nullable%253A%2520true%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520don't%2520set%2520init-value%2520here%2520because%2520this%2520would%2520be%2520assigned%2520to%2520ALL%2520elements%2520in%2520the%2520page!%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520set%2520this%2520to%2520%2522transparent%2522%2520in%2520decorator%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520check%253A%2520%2522Color%2522%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520gradientSteps%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520check%253A%2520%2522Array%2522%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520nullable%253A%2520true%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%252C%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520members%253A%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520_styleTextFillColor%253A%2520function%2520(styles)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520color%2520%253D%2520this.getTextFillColor()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(color%2520%253D%253D%253D%2520null)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520return%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520color%2520%253D%2520qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance().resolve(color)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520styles%255B%2522-webkit-text-fill-color%2522%255D%2520%253D%2520color%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520styles%255B%2522background-clip%2522%255D%2520%253D%2520%2522text%2522%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520gradientSteps%2520%253D%2520%2522%2522%252C%2520tmpColor%252C%2520tmpPosition%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520for%2520(var%2520i%2520%253D%25200%252C%2520len%2520%253D%2520this.getGradientSteps().length%253B%2520i%2520%253C%2520len%253B%2520i%252B%252B)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520keys%2520%253D%2520Object.keys(this.getGradientSteps()%255Bi%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tmpColor%2520%253D%2520qx.theme.manager.Color.getInstance().resolve(keys%255B0%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520tmpPosition%2520%253D%2520this.getGradientSteps()%255Bi%255D%255Bkeys%255B0%255D%255D%253B%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520gradientSteps%2520%252B%253D%2520%2522%252C%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520tmpColor%2520%252B%2520%2522%2520%2522%2520%252B%2520tmpPosition%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(%2522background-image%2522%2520in%2520styles)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(gradientSteps)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D)%253B%250A%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520var%2520match%2520%253D%2520%252F%252C%255B%255E%252C.%255D*%255B%2525%257Cpx%255D%255C)%252F.exec(styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520if%2520(match)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D%2520%253D%2520styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D.substr(0%252C%2520match.index)%2520%252B%2520gradientSteps%2520%252B%2520styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D.substr(match.index)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(styles%255B%2522background-image%2522%255D)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)%253B%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520patch%2520the%2520original%2520decorator%2520class%250Aqx.Class.patch(qx.ui.decoration.Decorator%252C%2520MExtendedLinearBackgroundGradient)%253B%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D)

Unfortunately I can't copy the whole example to the Playground because I get stupid errormessages like this one:  GlobalError: Could not refine property "textFillColor" without a "refine" flag in the property definition! This class: qx.ui.decoration.Decorator, original class: qx.ui.decoration.Decorator.

Those errors I don't get in my development-area. So I just copied and commented the mixin class in the playground.

The image above has been made with this decoration in my custom Decoration.js:

```
"myLabel": {
          decorator: [              
              MExtendedLinearBackgroundGradient
          ],
          style: {
              colorPositionUnit: "px",
              gradientStart: ["black", 20],
              gradientSteps: [{ "green": "20px" }, { "blue": "40px" }, { "red": "60px" }, { "yellow": "80px" }],
              gradientEnd: ["red", 100],
              textFillColor: "transparent"
         }
      }
```

Greetings
Ricky